# Issue in Material UI keyboard date picker for type a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

what happens if I select a date by clicking on the calendar it works fine but if the first time I set a date to empty and I will type the date it will not react like date format its go like **11111111111111111111** like this so its break the format of date but if I select from the calendar after that I will edit it work fine only first time if I will edit direct type it goes wrong.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <Grid container justifyContent="space-around">
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={formik.values.dob}
          onChange={handleChangeDate}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

[Code SandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fqqn6?file=/demo.js:632-1154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-date-picker-with-yup-validate-3odn7), that seems to do exactly what you are trying to do. Does it helps ?

Comment: I don't want to set today date in default I want to set the date format for inial it will appear like date format but in the first time going value not like date format

Comment: in first if i add date by typing its need to pe aspire like 12/06/2021 but my final value is coming like 12062021

Comment: I see, then I am going to edit this answer